# Why is Aperture 3.5.1 repeatedly crashing?

Tags: apple-aperture

I have about 100GB of photo data (16,000+ images) as referenced files residing on a portable 1.5 TB drive. This arrangement has worked well until recently, when I imported several new projects. As I navigate through the images, adding keywords and deleting unwanted shots, Aperture keeps crashing. It offers the choice to "reopen" and about half these occasions also requires me to "repair" the library, which takes several minutes.

Each time I reopen Aperture after these events, it seems to have remembered my previous changes, and I continue working at a new place each time. I take this to mean the problem is not a corrupted file.

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this aggravating phenomena? Could it be a hardware issue, like a bad cable to the portable drive? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A bad cable is the most likely reason for this. I've noticed (after extensively using USB, Firewire800 and eSATA) that USB is probably the least stable connection for an external drive. Firewire800 has been the best (most reliable) connection I've used for external drives.